# Is a url a valid value for a query param?

Tags: url

Is a URL a valid value for a query param? For instance:

`http://myapp.com/auth/login/jwt/new?referer=https://my-other-app.com`

Been Googling this and I've found no definite answer.

Comment: yes , if you can open it in browser it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was how Microsoft remember users' redirection URL after sucessfully logging in passport

Better way is to encodeURIComponent first

```
'? redirect=' + encodeURIComponent(url)
```

But you shouldn't pass referer in url. Referer is automatically set by browser in request header.